# Rails active admin and jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using jquery on my rails application especially for cloudinary, datepicker and modals, since the installation of active admin I noticed a conflict with jquery, if I require active_admin/base then the jquery of my app doesn't work inverted anymore if I remove the require, the jquery works on my app but not on active admin.

I've already read several posts on the subject but it's all starting to be old and none of them work for me.

active_admin.js

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require cloudinary/jquery.cloudinary
//= require attachinary
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require lunches
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: if that's the case, I'd prefer to sort of have namespaced assets, so you may have admin.js which loads `active_admin/base` and other shared asset dependencies, with main.js which loads the others and basically load whichever one depending on the view you're on

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your explanation, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving `active_admin.js` to `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory.

Comment: What does that exactly do?

Comment: I don't know how this works but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how you got to this solution, but thank you!